# error with adb push

Tags: adb

Hi I want to push an APK Expansion file to my phone so I am executing:

`C:\Users\dogface\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe push c
:\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb  /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.Audiobook\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb`

But that fails with this error:

`failed to copy 'c:\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb' to '/mnt/
sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.Audiobook\main.1.com.redcricket
.Audiobook.obb': Invalid argument`

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, especially for "Newbies": Hovering your mouse over the [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) tag will reveal some info. Clicking the [info](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) link there brings you to the tag wiki, providing you some information to get started. The second link there ([Everything about ADB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1241935)) contains the answer to your problem:

> `adb push C:\Desktop\TitaniumBackup.apk /sdcard/`

For the target, only specify the **path**, do not include a file name. So your command should look like:

```
adb.exe push c:\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.Audiobook
```

A special error you included is the backslash (`\`) which, on Windows systems, is a path separator -- but on Posix systems (Unix/Linux/Android) is an "escape character" (directory separator on these systems is the "forward slash", `/`).

Comment: Glad I could help -- and that it was such an easy solution :)